# How can we add Trello project data to google sheet manually without third party plugins?

Tags: api, google-apps-script, google-sheets, trello

how can we pull Trello project data into Google sheet without third party plugins and whenever a change made in Trello tickets it should automatically update the Google sheet?
I'm new to this please explain in details (codes will be helpful)

```
var url = 'https://api.trello.com/1/boards/' + trelloBoardId + '/cards?fields=id,name,desc,url&list=' + trelloListName + '&key=' + trelloApiKey + '&token=' + trelloApiToken;
e
 
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
  var data = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());
  
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  sheet.clearContents();
  
  var headers = ['ID', 'Name', 'Description', 'URL', 'Date'];
  sheet.appendRow(headers);
  
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    var row = [data[i].id, data[i].name, data[i].desc, data[i].url, data[i].Date];
    sheet.appendRow(row);
  }
}
```

not getting dates and also everytime I have to run using google script